# Function each() in PHP

Tags: php, each

```
<?php
require_once("entities/product.class.php");
require_once("entities/category.class.php");
$cates = Category::list_category();

session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

if(isset($_GET["id"])){
    $pro_id = $_GET["id"];
    $was_found = false;
    $i = 0;
    
    if(!isset($_SESSION["cart_items"]) || count($_SESSION["cart_items"])<1){
        $_SESSION["cart_items"] = array(0 => array("pro_id" => $pro_id, "Quantity" => 1));
    } else{
        foreach($_SESSION["cart_items"] as $item){
            $i++;
            while(list($key,$value) = each($item)){
                if($key=="pro_id" && $value==$pro_id){
                    array_splice($_SESSION["cart_items"], $i-1, 1, array(array("pro_id" => $pro_id, "Quantity" => $item["Quantity"]+1)));
                    $was_found = true;
                }
            }
        }
        if($was_found==false){
            array_push($_SESSION["cart_items"], array("pro_id" => $pro_id, "Quantity" =>1));
        }
    }
    header("location: shopping_cart.php");
}?>
```

There is my code. But it was error at function each() in while loop.

> Return the current key and value pair from an array and advance the array cursor
> each( array $array ): array
> Undefined function 'each'.intelephense(1010)

Please help me.

Comment: each() is deprecated.

Answer (score 4):

[each()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.each.php) is deprecated. Don't use it anymore. Use [foreach()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) instead.

Replace

```
while(list($key,$value) = each($item)) {
```

with

```
foreach($item as $key => $value) {
```